# ¿Cómo añadir información en excel sin perder la información con python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un trabajo de la Universidad y trato de hacer un sistema de recomendación colaborativo. Para ello, tengo un dataset y uso la información de él para hacer la recomendación.
Mi duda está en querer añadir información por columnas a un excel, donde el header de la columna sea un usuario y la fila sus usuarios más similares.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, haciendo el debido proceso querría añadir información en la columna F, donde la primera linea en esa columna sería el header y las demás sus usuarios similares.

Todo esto lo hago en python. Gracias de antemano por la atención prestada.

Comment: Que biblioteca usas para trabajar con el excel? Donde y con que formato tienes tus datos a guardar?. Generalmente usar una biblioteca especializada como  openpyxl o xlwings es lo mas simple para modificar un archivo ya existente. Agrega algo mas de información.

Comment: Estoy usando pandas para manejar todos los datos con data frames.

Answer (score 5):

Si lo que deseas es agregar columnas, un conjunto de columnas o un DataFrame entero a una hoja de Excel ya existente, usando ***openpyxl*** como engine para manejar el excel, puedes hacer algo como:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas.io.formats.excel

# Dataframe de prueba que vamos a agregar
df  = pd.DataFrame({'Header1': [45,  46,  47,  48],
                    'Header2': [51,  52,  53,  54],
                    'Header3': [61,  62,  63,  64]})

# Configuramos Pandas y cargamos el archivo correspondiente (en este caso se llama archivo.xlsx)                       
book = load_workbook('archivo.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('archivo.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book

# Por defecto Pandas formatea las celdas del header con negrita y borde, si no se quiere hacemos lo siguiente:
pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None

# Guardamos el df en el excel en el lugar apropiado.
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df.to_excel(writer, book.worksheets[0].title, startcol = 5,  index = False) 
writer.save()
```

Cabe detenerse un poco en la línea:

```
df.to_excel(writer, book.worksheets[0].title, startcol = 5,  index = False)
```

- `book.worksheets[0].title` es la hoja en la que queremos guardar. en este caso es la primera hoja del workbook. Tambien podemos usar directamente el nombre de esta, p.e: `"sheet1"`.
- Para guardar en un lugar concreto de la hoja se usan los argumentos `startcol` y `startrow`. Ambos son indices numéricos que empiezan a numerar desde 0 y no desde 1. En este caso la columna "F" es el indice 5 (`startcol = 5`).
- Con `index = False` le indicamos que no incluya el indice del DataFrame. En caso contrario no pasar este argumento.

Ver [documentación de `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) para más información.

En nuestro ejemplo la salida será:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cual fue el código que ejecutaste para abrir el archivo con los nuevos datos agregados??